# Is the autocomplete only about Back and Forward button and their history, but not about history, bookmark, revisit, or suggestion?

Tags: html

I found the specs for the HTML `autocomplete` attribute here:

> http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete

But it doesn't mention when it is applied to.  It seems like when it is `on`, then that means a user can press the Back and Forward button of the browser and the data will be kept in the input text box,  or if the user chooses a history item using the Back and Forward button area.  And when it is `off`, that means the data should not be kept in the input box.

And it is ***not*** about:

1. the history window bringing a page back (after clicking on a history item)
2. any bookmark bringing a page back
3. typing in the same URL in the browser
4. suggestion, such as when a user typed in "macbook" before, now the user types in "mac", and it tries to suggest "macbook" either just inside the input box (but with the "book" part highlighted so the user can keep on typing, or by showing an extra pop up box down under the input text box, for a list of suggestions.
5. since any time a user exits the browser, for what is known as a "session end", then by (1) to (4) above, there is no way that the data will follow the `autocomplete="on"` behavior.

Is this the exact behavior of `autocomplete`?  (any pointers to a more exact spec will be appreciated).

I made a static webpage and tried it on a Macbook locally using Apache and `localhost://try.html`, but the basic behavior can be tested here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jzNTM/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/jzNTM/4/

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete:  Should the browser remember answers for the given field.  (number 4 in your list)
autocomplete="on" is the default
Say you have a social-security-number input field

```
<input name="ssn" placeholder="xxx-xx-xxxx" />
```

If I enter 555-55-5555 the browser will remember that answer
If I (or anyone else) comes back to the form later and start to type "5" into the field, the browser will auto-complete / auto-suggest "555-55-5555"
For something sensative like a SSN, this is probably most undesireable.  (great way to harvest personal data from a public computer)

Adding autocomplete="off" to the input (or form) will prevent the browser from remembering entered values

```
<input name="ssn" placeholder="xxx-xx-xxxx" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: but I don't see (4) happening whether it is `autocomplete="on"` vs `"off"`

Comment: in IE, autocomplete can be completely disabled  
via Tools / Internet Options / Content / Autocomplete